# find the container of each task in hadoop 2.7.2 in master:8088

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

after running a job on hadoop 2.7.2 with two slaves,I want to know the container of each tasks.in master:8088 we can see the maximum and minimum allocation.
[image: master:8088]

when I click on applicatio....004,it show this picture ,which shows memmory0 and vcore0.[image: applicstion..004]

I want to know how I can find the container's properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your application has finished that 2nd screen above shows the Aggregate Resource Allocation.

To see the container state at run time, open the web browser at "URL:8042/node/allContainers" where URL is the public DNS of your cluster. You will see all the containers of running applications. Click on the container ID for your app. How do you know which app ID ? That is from the above 2 screens.

See if this helps.